# How do you have a person asking: ["What is your answer?" he said.]

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks

How do you have a person asking:

> *"What is your answer?" he said.*

Should the "he said" part be capitalized? Does the question mark come after the comment or after the 'he said' part?

Comment: That's rather a toughie and the easy way out would be to switch it into 

He said "What is your answer?"

Comment: Convention is to treat the question-mark as the equivalent of a comma in direct speech, so _he_ remains uncapitalised. The reverse happens after Dear Sir, [You will be ...]. The position of the question mark has been covered here many times (and probably shouldn't have, being general reference).

Answer (score 2):

The "he" is not capitalized.

In quotations, the question mark goes inside the quote if it is part of a quote

> He asked, "What is your answer?"
>
> "What is your answer?" he asked.

but outside the quote if it is not.

> Did he say, "I have an answer"?

Note that if you ask a question about a question, you only use one question mark inside.

> Did he ask, "What is your answer?"